# WSO2 API Manager authentication through single page app

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 API Manager. I have installed it to proxy my REST endpoints and to do access management via oAuth2.
Great! I managed to get access to my backend REST implementation through the oAuth2 process of API Manager (via API console). Now I want to setup the complete roundtrip starting from a user authentication process where identity is verified with corresponding roles. So...

Next I want to create a single page app and bring an authentication step by either redirect the user to a login page (authentication service) or let the user interact with single app page directly and let the single app page do the login to some authentication service.

**Question:**
Can I use the Key Manager component of the API Manager to handle user authentication (oAuth2 based) or do I need to install the WSO2 Identity Server to handle the authentication?

I see that WSO2 API Manager can host Users and Roles, a User Store and an endpoint to handle (authz) token requests, but can it also handle a login (authentication) request from my single app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use APIM with OAuth2 Authorization code grant type. See [this sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Setting+up+the+Sample+Webapp) in identity server docs, but use below endpoints of APIM instead of IS endpoints.

```
https://localhost:8243/authorize
https://localhost:8243/token
```